# how to add break line between 2 strings of chunk_split

Tags: php, chunks

I am trying to send 2 strings to mail with attachment using php. Everything is working fine except I get 2 strings without space between them. I want 2nd string on new line. How to achieve this. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

My code:

```
 //Capture POST data from HTML form and Sanitize them, 
    $sender_name    = filter_var($_POST["sender_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //sender name
    $reply_to_email = filter_var($_POST["sender_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //sender email used in "reply-to" header
    $fname        = filter_var($_POST["fname"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    $lname        = filter_var($_POST["lname"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);



//plain text 
        $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
        $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($fname)); 
        $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($lname));
```

I want line break between fname and lname. Thank you.

Comment: Can i have sample output of email that is currently sending ?

Answer (score 0):

IF you are looking this output from a browser, you must use `<br>`

Try this,

```
$fname="shashank";
$lname="shah";
$body = "--$boundary\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
$body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($fname)); 
$body .= "<br>";
$body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($lname));  
echo $body;
```

Another way would be

```
$body .= nl2br(chunk_split(base64_encode($fname))."\n".chunk_split(base64_encode($lname)));
```

Comment: It gives me error: --8de2a431c506316063ec3a4044192e46 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1 Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 cG9v amE= Thank you for your email ....                                                    
And also in my inbox I got only attachment

Comment: @pkm can i have what you've tried because as per my answer you only have to add $body .= "<br>"; nothing more than that.

Comment: Above answer will help you to only breaking firstname and lastname. "And also in my inbox I got only attachment " would be separate question.

Comment: I have tried your code as it is. I simply wrote..   $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($fname)); 
        $body .= "<br>";
        $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($lname));

Comment: Create a file and put my code and see your desire result will be there.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try using PHP_EOL

e.g. `$body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($fname)).PHP_EOL;`

Comment: It gives me string without space.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching, I found that just appending a keyboard return inside a string after each var worked. Not the most elegant solution, but did the trick.

```
$fname = filter_var($_POST["fname"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) .'
';
$lname = filter_var($_POST["lname"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```